# Fork 3 repo's into 1 main one

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a specific problem in git which I havent found an answer to yet.
In gitlab I have 3 seperate repos. For my school project the teacher wants me to copy everything into a repo of his and wants to see all my git history.

So I would need to fork my 3 repos into his main repo, but I just couldnt figure out an answer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you specify unambiguously, precisely, objectively, what, *exactly* you mean by "copy everything into a repo", "see all git history", and "fork a repo into a repo"?

Comment: @JörgWMittag So I have worked on 3 repos that I created. My teacher wants all my code copied(forked) on his own repo and he also wants to see my git activity. So I would need to somehow fork my 3 repos into his repo, which i have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three approaches you might consider for merging three repositories into a single repository. For clarity, I'll call your three repos `A`, `B`, and `C`, and the combined repository will be called `teacher`.

### One repository, multiple branches

One repository can have multiple branches, not just `master`. As far as Git is concerned there is not a huge difference between maintaining multiple repositories or multiple branches. So what you can do is the following:

1. create the `teacher` repository
2. add the `teacher` repository as a “remote” of A,B,C
3. for each of A,B,C push the branches to the `teacher` repo under a suitable name. E.g you might push A's master branch as `A/master`. The `git push` command can choose a different remote name, e.g. `git push local-branch:name-in-remote`.

### Git-Submodule

Git can link a folder to another repository as a submodule. When the `teacher` repository is checked out, the submodules can be checked out as well. A submodule is not part of the `teacher` repository so the history is not copied, but the submodule refers to a specific commit in the linked repository, thus referencing the correct history.

### Git-Subtree

Git can perform a special kind of merge where you merge another branch into a folder. This performs a copy but keeps any history intact.

1. create the `teacher` repository
2. for each of A,B,C use git-subtree to merge that repository's master branch into a suitable folder in the `teacher` repo. For example, you might include the A master branch into a folder called `A/`.

Git-subtree has a similar effect to creating a new repository and manually copying the files into that repository, but unlike a manual copy all the history will be kept intact. It is therefore better to view the subtree approach as a kind of merging technique.

---

Please ask your teacher which approach they would prefer. If in doubt the git-subtree approach is likely best and easiest to use because it includes the complete history of all repositories into a single branch of a single repository. However, note that this will not work as easily if your A,B,C repositories contain multiple branches.

Comment: Thank you for this very informative comment. I will be looking into git subtrees. And will mark this as answered my question